# Joda time. Как выполнять функцию в определенный момент

Tags: java, spring, jodatime

К примеру есть функция `foo()`.
Как вызывать ее к примеру каждый день в hh 00:00

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       foo();
    }

    private static void foo() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

}
```

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/timer.php

Comment: https://www.codeflow.site/ru/article/java-timer-and-timertask

Comment: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/quick-start.html